# Is MonoType related to C#'s Type (as in typeof)

Tags: mono, embedded

I am using the InteralCall method of calling C from C#, something like the sample given [here](http://old.kov.eti.br/programacao/mono/hb/go-mono.com/tutorial/html/en/embeding/embeddc.html) but I am passing in a Type object.

```
class Hello {
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        extern static void Sample (Type t);
}
```

So in my C code, I'd typically use MonoObject to receive the C# object. I want to convert or cast this to a MonoClass* or perhaps MonoType* so I can start calling mono_object_new() later on and create many objects. Of course, if I use mono_object_get_class I'd get the class for the actual Type class. I need something that converts C#'s Type into MonoClass*.

```
static void Sample (MonoObject* t) 
        {
                // I want to convert the MonoObject* argument to a MonoClass*
        }
```

My code is a bit more involved but this illustrates what I am trying to do. I could create a dummy object and pass that instead, and get the class by using mono_object_get_class() but I'm curious if I can do it using Type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C type that represents a C# System.Type is MonoReflectionType* (still a MonoObject*).

To get the MonoType* you can use in most of the rest of the embedding API you call mono_reflection_type_get_type ().

The MonoType* pointer is analogous to the TypeHandle in C# land.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the clarification. I'll give that a shot and report back.